# Code snippet 'external library' is stacking files backwards

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

When using the 'external library' function in Code Snippets, the files are stacking up backwards, where the *last* file is placed on *top* of the previous one.  The JavaScript framework pulldowns do the same thing.

You're logically going down the list and adding things...

1. Select jQuery version from the pull down.
2. Use 'external library' link to add jQuery plugin #1.
3. Use 'external library' link to add jQuery plugin #2 (depends on plugin #1).

... this is what you'll get...

```
<script src="plugin_2.js"></script>
<script src="plugin_1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
```

... completely upside down from how you really wanted them stacked.  (*Note that when using [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net), 'External Resources' are stacked exactly in the same order as you enter them.*)

I sometimes find myself forgetting that I need to think backwards and then end up doing some cutting and pasting.  Not a big deal, but this is another little thing that makes using jsFiddle somewhat easier and more intuitive.

Verified in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Comment: But jsFiddle does not add the `<script>` into the html view, stack snippets do. The system will have a hard time figuring out where to insert the next reference if it can't just insert at the top.

Comment: As someone who is beginning to use more and more javascript, I imagine this is a nightmare.

Comment: @gunr2171, I appreciate the technical differences with jsFiddle, however, this issue can be a pain to work with after adding a bunch of scripts in the wrong order.  Why can't it just insert after the last occurrence of `</script>`?

Comment: What if that last occurrence is at the bottom or middle of your code? I'd imagine there would be a lot of edge cases to worry about.

Comment: @gunr2171, No matter how you do it, something like this will have edge cases and ways to break it.  IMO, don't worry about a few edge cases when 99.9% of users have to deal with upside down file stacking.

Comment: @gunr2171, until one of the SO mods or developers explains why it's doing something illogical and counter-intuitive, it's a bug.

Comment: I think @gunr2171 has got the wrong idea here, it's not the positioning of the script tags, it's the order.

Comment: @Joe, you need to know the position of the script tags to be able to make the order correct.

Comment: @gunr2171 .. no? You place them in one block, ordered the same as they are when you add them. The first reference I add, should be at the top of the block, second reference, below that, etc.

Comment: That only works if all the external references are the first lines of the html code. As soon as you put your scripts inside your code this will break.

Comment: @gunr2171, Not if you're only looking for the last occurrence of a `</script>` tag that immediately comes after a `<script>` tag containing a `src` attribute.

Comment: ... you realise that the issue being reported here is the order is reversed, right? Positioning of the script elements is largely irrelevant, the order is not.

Comment: @Joe, I understand what's going on. If you assume that all external references are at a block at the very beginning of the html code, then sure, the system can add a line at the end of the block. But I'm done arguing this.

Comment: @gunr2171, in this case, the only time it's not going to be in a block at the beginning is when you _manually_ move it elsewhere.  In that case, you're doing it manually and any "automatic" file insertion is irrelevant since you've decided to over-ride the feature.

Comment: This is very irritating issue and can be fixed very easily, something like `$("script:last").append()` ..?  I wonder why this is being ignored or taking so much time for status completion.

Comment: @TJ, I stopped using snippets and went back to jsFiddle because of this.