# Edits from different tabs being added as new answers

Tags: bug, stack-snippets, multiple-answers

Very weird things happened today:

I saw a question, which can be answered better with a demo. So I opened a
new [jsFiddle window](http://jsfiddle.net/) (*see at the bottom why*).

I added some CSS, made a demo in jsFiddle and came back to my answer and clicked the stack snippet button:

A white box opens up, and stays as it is for a long time (*see below*). I got frustrated and thought at least I could fix the minor formatting in the mean time while the snippet window loaded completely. Hence I duplicated the tab (*using the duplicate option of Google Chrome*) - a new tab opened where my post was in edit mode, without the snippet window opened. 5 minutes didn't pass, so I fixed the formatting issue and clicked OK - it became a new answer..!

Wow... that is scary. I quickly deleted it, closed the duplicated tab, and ran away from there.

Now Chrome took me back to the original tab, snippet hadn't loaded yet, and the UI was not accessible. So:

- I clicked reload
- The page asked me whether to leave the page or not
- I clicked OK and reloaded the page
- Edited the existing post which was not deleted
- Opened the stack snippet window (*this time it loaded*)
- Pasted the code from jsFiddle to stack snippet, clicked insert and
  post.
- The page asked me to perform the [reCAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReCAPTCHA), which I passed and the page refreshed

It became another answer..!

This is the order in which things happened to the best of my knowledge (*I somewhat panicked while all this happened, seeing myself posting multiple answers*). I added content in the post-your-answer area and clicked the post-your-answer-button **only once** - the very first time. The rest were edits.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27457795/2333214) is the above mentioned post. Screenshot of edits that became additional answers within the grace period:

[image]

---

I went to jsFiddle to make a demo because it has a nice list of libraries, and I can choose the libraries I want to include very quickly (*[jQuery UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI) in this case*). When it comes to stack snippet, we're on our own, despite [all the feature requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271776/2333214), sadly.

I usually create the demo in a jsFiddle window and without saving the code there, I'll inspect it, copy the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) to libraries one by one from the head section (*of course in [reverse order](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276610/2333214)*) as well as the code to stack snippet :/

---

Here is the frustrating white box (*I am not sure how many of you have ever seen this; I have a very pathetic Internet connection. I have to live with it :*):

[image]

Comment: Sometimes I have seen that white box too. But after some seconds it loads the snippet editor.

Comment: Never ever again, go through the dark alleyways.

Comment: as programmers: ***duplication is evil***.