# Edited an existing answer, yet it posted a new answer

Tags: bug, edits, answers

I wrote an answer to a question which had a slight flaw in the logic. I clicked the `edit` button below the answer to amend it. The answer was replaced by the usual editor, pre-populated with my answer in markdown format.

Once I made the change I pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd> to save the changes, yet it did not work. I was confused at this point and just clicked the button manually with the mouse (I assume this was the 'Save edits' button, but I didn't realise there was an issue at this point to note the actual text)

I then realised my edit had been added as a new answer, instead of as an update to my previous one. I immediately deleted this new answer and repeated the process to edit my original answer, and this time it worked successfully.

I was confused at first and thought I must have clicked 'post another answer' by mistake, but I am certain that I didn't do that because there was no alert to confirm I wanted to add another answer, and also the markdown editor was pre-populated with my original answer text - it was not empty.

For reference:

The question: [Access outside root div from a click with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38718107/519413)

The original answer which I attempted to edit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38718226/519413

The duplicate answer which should have been saved as an update: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38718261/519413

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280179/6083675

Comment: @Laurel This was all done within a single tab; I did not have multiple tabs open on SO